# Redis PHP cache "ERR Not permitted"

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, redis, phpredis

I'm trying to get a [Redis front-end cache to Wordpress](https://gist.github.com/JimWestergren/3053250#file-index-with-redis-php) to work.  I get this fatal error:

```
    2013-06-07 01:46:12: (mod_fastcgi.c.2701) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Predis\ServerException' with message 'ERR operation not permitted' in /home/www/predis/lib/Predis/Client.php:291
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/www/predis/lib/Predis/Client.php(233): Predis\Client->onResponseError(Object(Predis\Command\HashExists), Object(Predis\ResponseError))
    #1 /home/www/index-with-redis.php(76): Predis\Client->__call('hexists', Array)
    #2 /home/www/index-with-redis.php(76): Predis\Client->hexists('7de22495a3e5275...', '3e3299d491f3bac...')
    #3 {main}
      thrown in /home/www/predis/lib/Predis/Client.php on line 291
```

I have a functioning Redis-server (running other projects with it).  For some reason, I get a `ERR Not permitted`.  Any ideas?

Comment: OK - this was due to Redis db being password protected - a detail I had not included in my php script. FFR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said in your comment, the problem is the password not set. For anyone seeing this error in the future, you want to instantiate your client with:

```
my_client = new Predis\Client(array(
            "host" => "some_host",
            "port" => "some_port",
            "password" => "some_pw",
            "database" => "some_db_number"
        )
```